# Which data is collected by Google Analytics PageView?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, google-analytics, tracking

I am reviewing the privacy of data collected by Google Analytics when collecting on the default PageView action. Here is the code snippet being used:

```
<script> 
                (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){

                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),

                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)

                })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                ga('create', 'UA-1111111-11', 'auto'); 
                ga('send', 'pageview'); 
</script>
```

I can't find any clear answer as to exactly which data is being collected. I want to make sure that no PII or PHI will be collected by accident if the page being tracked contains some, such as name, phone, medical info, etc.

Is there any clear guide that states which data is collected for PageView?

Comment: [When all this information is collected, it is sent to the Analytics servers in the form of a long list of parameters attached to a single-pixel GIF image request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview) So you can just inspect the page, click network, and look at the get parameters.

Comment: @Marie I have read this but didn't find anywhere that specifies explicitly which details are tracked for the PageView action

Comment: You can look at what it is tracking. Just click F12 and click the network tab. Beyond that at the bottom of the page it shows you example data of what is tracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default no PII should be collected by pageviews** since the pageview data contains:

- `Page URL / Page title`: which is publicly available information about others things (whatever content is on the website) and not the user itself
- `User browser / system info`: which is technical information (eg browser version)

Like Marie explained, this is something you can verify yourself by inspecting the browser console, when browsing Stackoverflow for instance:

[image]

The payload being:

> v=1&_v=j68&a=1398701675&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Stack%20Overflow%20-%20Where%20Developers%20Learn%2C%20Share%2C%20%26%20Build%20Careers&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1840x486&je=0&_u=SACAAEABE~&jid=&gjid=&cid=1389717770.1529853314&uid=148108&tid=UA-108242619-1&_gid=263772020.1532245622&cd1=148108&cd3=Home%2FIndex&z=522475539

**However in some cases, pageviews can collect PII**, the most common case being that if the page URL or titles contain PII. I've faced such a situation with a company who were running GA on their intranet, and PII was getting exposed in 2 ways:

- `Employee profiles`: https://myintranet.net/employees/firstname-lastname
- `Employee search`: the most common use task of the intranet (large corporate) was to look people up via their email address, resulting in a search parameter added to the URL (https://myintranet.net/search/q=f.lastname@company.com) which was getting tracked as both pageview AND [search keyword](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=internal_search&jump=ga_searchkeyword) by GA

**General remark about PII warnings**: you simply won't find them. Google will not engage their liability saying something does or does not contain PII for the reason that it's out of their control: analytics implementations are customizable, and therefore any data point can potentially contain PII. So it's up to you (testing before implementation, monitoring once live) to ensure your GA implementation doesn't contain PII. If it does, you'll get a warning from Google. If you don't take any actions to correct it, they will shut down your account.

Comment: Max - thanks! Can you please tell me where you found which fields are collected (i.e. page url/title, user browser/system info)? Is there an official Google link stating that?

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#gifParameters. If you're happy with the answer you can accept it :)